# Compare Two Hebrew Strings Alphabetically

Tags: vb.net, compare, hebrew

I know that I can use the `String.Compare(StringA, StringB)` to compare two strings and see which one comes first alphabetically

However, I tried this with two Hebrew strings, and it doesn't compare alphabetically.

Is there another way to do this, or do I have to change something with the encoding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
String.Compare(StringA, StringB, new CultureInfo("he"), CompareOptions.None)
```

where `he` is the code for Hebrew.

There are several overloads for `Compare`. [Here is the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190529(v=vs.110).aspx) for the example above.

Comment: I learned something new today. Thanks. Question : I was just reading [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(vs.71).aspx). Does it accept ISO code as well as whats mentioned in the doc?

Comment: I'm just curious. I tried your code and it said culturenotfound exception

Comment: read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx#CultureNames

Comment: Sorry to bother you, i'm just doing this for learning purpose. But even with `HE` doesnt work. https://dotnetfiddle.net/r3P849 I'm sure im doing something wrong :)

Comment: Did you try lowercase ("he") as Daniel suggested? It is explained in the paragraph he linked to.

Comment: Or try `he-IL` as your option.

Comment: @TheUknown `.Compare` returns an `int32`. so if they are equal its `0`.